# Couldn't a boy simply fly into Girls' dorm?

Tags: harry-potter

Hermione was able to go into boys' dorm. I remember her talking with Harry and Ron while sitting on one of the bed in Harry's room in Gryffindor Tower. On the other hand, stairs didn't allow Harry and Ron to go into girls' dorm. The reason given was: Boys aren't trustworthy.

But, if I was at Hogwarts, provided that I could fly on brooms, what could prevent me to go into girls' dorm? Was there any other magic in place?

Comment: Prefects. Head Boys/Girls. Tattlers.

Answer (score 7):

> He bounded forwards, pulled open the door and set off up the **spiral staircase**.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - p.314 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 17, *Educational Decree Number Twenty-four*

I don't think a broom would fit up the staircase. Possibly through the windows, but I would imagine they'd be too small.

On the whole, though, I think providing a simple, sensible, almost fun precaution is one thing. I don't think taking an obvious mitigatory step implies that the founders' foresaw a need to barricade the girls in and somehow overlooked an obvious loophole. I close my windows and lock my front door when I leave the house. I don't have a moat a drawbridge and windows too narrow to get through!

Answer (score 2):

I have trouble believing that if stairs could turn themselves into a slide, that there would not be some other form of charm or enchantment on the stairwell itself to prevent such an action.

I am unaware of anything even remotely canonical that would suggest this though - as a franchise, Harry Potter kept itself remarkably clean of any real lewd/suggestive material, and that Marauder's Map tongue-in-cheek joke aside, I can't even think of anything in the movies or books that was remotely suggestive of students having those types of relations.

Comment: Percy got a girlfriend in the second book. It was disclosed by his little sister which shook lots of guys. Also, in the fourth book, Snape caught someone coming out of bush or something like that. While such relations weren't common, it was in existence.

Comment: Also, if stair magic was in place, it means history has seen such things.

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 That sort of answers your own question. These incidences were caught by staff or reported by other students, just as they would be in other boarding schools without magic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can. If it is emergency, boys, especially prefects or headboys can fly towards girls dormitory. The magic in staircase is just a warning for boys that they cannot enter there without emergency as girls want more privacy compared to boys and puberty controls boys more than girls. However, if a boy use broomstick only for fun or less trustworthy reasons, he will get punishment

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this that you could [edit] in?